# I need a way to make a multiple text output onclick button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

For a project I am doing I want a button that when clicked will cause a text that is not the button to change to a new text every time clicked. For example first time click, "example 1" second, "example 2" another, "example 3" etc...

I have tried a few things from my limited programming knowledge but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var time = 0, output = document.getElementById("output");
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
  time++;
  if (time == 1) output.textContent = "1";
  else if (time == 2) output.textContent = "2";
  else if (time == 3) output.textContent = "3";
  // repeat that pattern as many times as you want
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click me!</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

EDIT:

Instead of using if/else statements, you should look into a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick improvement based on the still accurate answer @VirxEC provided above. Rather than checking for the first, second, or third time, we simply display the time variable. I also appended the word "example" as the user described when asking the question.

```js
var time = 0, output = document.getElementById("output");
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
  time++;
  output.textContent = "example " + time;
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click me!</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```